# String parse method not working correctly

Tags: c#, parsing, int, hex

I'm trying to parse a string containing a Hex. I need to split it into two parts and convert each into a character. The first part works correctly, but the second returns a number instead of a character.

```
string chr = "E583";    
string result = "";

for (int u = 0; u < chr.Length; u += 2) 
  result += (char)int.Parse(
    chr.Substring(u, 2), 
    System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber);
```

This function returns `"å\u0083"`. The first character translates correctly, the second remains a Hex. Why? Is there a better way of coding this? Thanks! :)

Comment: Thanks, I corrected it.

Comment: Well, `\u0083` code is *invisible* character "No Break Here" https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0083/index.htm that's why it's represesnted in debuger like this

Comment: But technically speaking, the character should appear as ƒ, but it doesn't.

Comment: It's not `'f'` just have a look: `((int) ('f')).ToString("x2")` is `0x66`, not `0x83`

Comment: This is the original string: "åƒ" which I then transform into a Hex string "E583" and I need to later convert back to "åƒ" using the above code, but what I get is "å\u0083".

Comment: Let's encode it: `var encoded = string.Concat("åƒ".Select(c => ((int)c).ToString("X")));` I've got `"E5192"`, not `"E583"`. Please, check your encoding routine

Comment: If you look at the ASCII table "83" corresponds to "ƒ" and "E5" corresponds to "å". But the real problem here is getting these Hex codes to translate back to the proper original symbols. I've tried the above function with other byte pairs and I always get the same thing: the first translates correctly, the second doesn't.

Comment: https://www.tamasoft.co.jp/en/general-info/unicode.html

Comment: `var bytes = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes("åƒ"); var encoded = string.Concat(bytes.Select(c => c.ToString("X2")));` . Reverse with:  `var hexBytes = new List<byte>(); for (int i = 0; i < encoded.Length; i += 2) { hexBytes.Add(byte.Parse(encoded.Substring(i, 2), NumberStyles.HexNumber)); } string original = Encoding.Unicode.GetString(hexBytes.ToArray());`. Forget about what there was in the Extended ASCII table.

Comment: Thank you Jimi, but this code combines the bytes into a chinese symbol: ""襕"". I need them separated. In other words, I need to get two distnct characters: "ƒ" and "å".

Comment: Thar's what that code does. The `encoded` string contains the hex representation of the Unicode codepoints: `E5009201`. The `original` string contains the starting values: `åƒ`. If you need the distinct chars, use, e.g.,  `var chars = original.ToCharArray();`. `chars[0]` is `å`. You can *work* with ASCII values if you remain in the 0-127 domain.

Comment: What my code is trying to do is start from "襕", then split it into two distinct characters: "ƒ" and "å". So perhaps my way of doing it is not correct. Is there an easier and more efficient way of doing it?

Comment: `"襕"` is a Unicode symbol. It's represented by the `\u8955` CodePoint. Byte[0] = `85` (`0x55`), Byte[1] = `137` (`0x89`). You can map the first byte (`85`) to an ASCII char representation. Not the second, its *value* is `> 127`. You should explain what you're actually trying to do here.

Comment: I'm reading a file that contains "åƒ", I'm combining the two bytes to obtain "襕" and I write this character to file. Then, I need to read it back, split it up again and write "åƒ" to file.

Comment: This is **not** what you want to do, at all. These values depend on the Encoding. You're probably using a Local Encoding. Or transforming arbitrary values to Unicode CodePoints. It's a recipe for disaster. IMO, find another method for whatever you're tryuing to do.